# Using 22.04 Network menu to VPN with Pulse Secure

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openconnect

I can use the PulseUI GUI to VPN to a university I'm working with.
It uses Duo-push authentication and works fine.
What I don't like is that the GUI won't autofill the password fields.

I can invoke `openconnect` from the command-line as well.
The VPN works fine but I can't pass the two passwords on the command-line or through stdin.

The Ubuntu `openconnect-network-manager-gui` supports the Pulse Secure protocol and should autofill the password fields once I've established a valid connection.
It does give the Duo-push but says that it can't connect and I don't know why.

Given that `openconnect` does work, I'm wondering if I need to set some extra parameters in the menu or if there's some extra library that I need to install.

Comment: This is the command-line for the `openconnect`:
```
sudo openconnect --protocol=pulse -u $VPNID $SERVER
```

Answer (score 0):

Wellll... it seems to be working now. One thing is that it was blinking off-and-on a few times but the Duo handshake did show up on my phone, without me having to type anything in, which is what I was wanting.

There may be a way to have it run a little more more cleanly, but I think I should just close this for now.